# Tabbar icons all loading except first one. Works in simulator. Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm loading up all the tab bar images and the images load on the simulator but the first tab bar item image doesn't load on device.

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;

UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *item3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
[item0 setTitle:@"icon1"];
[item1 setTitle:@"icon2"];
[item2 setTitle:@"icon3"];
[item3 setTitle:@"icon4"];


[item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1"]];
[item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CalendarIconSelected"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CalendarIconSelected"]];
[item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"News"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"News"]];
[item3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Events"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Events"]];



[item1 imageInsets];
[item2 imageInsets];
[item3 imageInsets];
```

Comment: check and recheck capital letters in filenames - is it Icon1.png or icon1.PNG. In this case file would show up in simulator but not on device.

Comment: Glad to hear. This simulator behaviour is somewhat missleading and can lead to loosing an hour or more of precious time :)

Comment: [item0 imageInsets];
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite common scenario is mistyped filename. For some reason simulator is not case-sensitive with image files. Device on the other hand is.

So check and double-check each character in filename. Is it Icon1.png or icon1.PNG.

Comment: Also it may be helpful to add that if you provide a filename without an extension, it will automatically look for PNG files with that name, i.e. if you specify a name of simply `"icon1"` when your image is named "icon1.png", it will still be found and used.